# WAI tutorial - no instance for (Show Response)

Tags: haskell, response, haskell-wai, haskell-warp

Again the n00b here: trying Warp and WAI with the following code as in the documentation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
app3 :: Application
app3 request respond = respond $ case rawPathInfo request of
    "/"     -> index
    "/raw/" -> plainIndex
    _       -> notFound

plainIndex :: Response
plainIndex = responseFile
    status200
    [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    "index.html"
    Nothing

notFound :: Response
notFound = responseLBS
    status404
    [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    "404 - Not Found"
```

Running plainIndex in GHCi returns:

```
<interactive>:12:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show Response) arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
*Main> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( WAI.hs, interpreted )
```

Two questions in one: can you help me out fixing this, and in exension to that: I am the only one frequently encountering issues like this when following documentation examples?

Answer (score 1):

Running `plainIndex` in GHCi, GHCi tries to compute the `Response` and then print it in the terminal.  A `Show` instance defines how a given type should be represented as a `String`.  The library authors have chosen not to provide a `Show` instance for `Response`, probably to separate its representation from its interface.

Various parts of a response have `Show` instances, so you can use [accessors provided by Wai](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.2/docs/Network-Wai.html#g:6):

```
> responseStatus plainIndex
> responseHeaders plainIndex
```

More [documentation for Response](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.2/docs/Network-Wai.html#g:4).